# Go exec does not capture git log output

Tags: git, go, command-line-interface

I'm translating our Cli tool written in Ruby (using Thor) to Go.

Up until now I've had no issues with passing git commands and capturing the output I want.

The general code I use when I want an output is:

```
func output(c string, args []string, printOut bool) (string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(c, args...)

    if verbose {
        text.Command(c, args)
    }

    if printOut {
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    }

    output, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        reportError()

        return "", err
    }

    reportOk()

    return string(output), nil
}
```

I'm having some issues with the following command though:

`git --no-pager log --merges --grep='^merge.*(hotfix|release)|(.*from.*(hotfix|release))' --regexp-ignore-case --perl-regexp --pretty=format:%H -n 1`

I'm calling the output like this:

```
    args := []string{
        "--no-pager", "log", "--merges", "--grep='^merge.*(hotfix|release)|(.*from.*(hotfix|release))'", "--regexp-ignore-case", "--perl-regexp", "--pretty=format:%H", "-n", "1",
    }

    out, err := output(cmd, args, false)
```

For some context, this command is used to find the hash of the last release/hotfix merge, in order to find all relevant commits to add to the changelog, from that commit until 'now'.

If I remove `--grep='^merge.*(hotfix|release)|(.*from.*(hotfix|release))' --regexp-ignore-case --perl-regexp`, I do get a commit hash output, but I need the regex to make sure its a merge I want.

The thing is `cmd.Output()` does not return an error when I pass the full command, it simply returns an empty string.

The full command works when executed on the terminal.

Does anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Passing a shell to execute the full command works: `cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "git --no-pager log --merges --grep='^merge.*(hotfix|release)|(.*from.*(hotfix|release))' --regexp-ignore-case --perl-regexp --pretty=format:%H -n 1")`

Answer (score 2):

You're invoking `git grep` *without* letting `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` or whatever shell<sup>1</sup> get its grubby little paws on the command first.

When using `--grep`, we (by which I mean humans typing commands into shells) write thing like:

```
git log --grep='^merge|whatever' whatever-else
```

with the single quotes here to *protect the pattern from the shell*.  The single quotes make sure that the vertical bar `|` character is not treated as a pipe-to, i.e., this is not the command:

```
git log --grep=^merge | whatever ...
```

which would pipe the output from `git log --grep=^merge` to `whatever`.

**We need the quote here because the shell is interpreting our command, and treats some character specially; the single quotes defeat this, and get consumed *by* the shell in the process.**  That means *Git* sees `--grep=^merge|whatever`, for instance.

But **you're not invoking the shell**.  There is nothing to protect.  So you're instructing Git to look for `'^merge`, i.e., a single quote followed by a hat/caret `^` followed by an `m` followed by an `e` and so on.  That doesn't exist in any of your commits, so you are not getting the output you expect.

The solution is trivial: stop quoting things against the non-existent shell, so that you aren't passing unexpected quotes to Git.  If you *do* need to use the shell for some reason, keep the quotes, but pay very close attention to everything else, since careless invocation of shells causes 28.41% of all CVEs (this statistic, like 72.93% of all statistics, was made up on the spot).

---

<sup>1</sup>On some systems, `/bin/sh` *is* `/bin/bash`; on some it's `dash`; on some it's some other variant.  This creates portability annoyances sometimes.  Here it's not critical as all shells treat these the same.